# How to highlight non-main diagonal elements

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-styles

I was wondering how to highlight diagonal elements of pandas DataFrame using df.style methods.

I already found out how to do it with the main diagonal, but can't manage to highlight the one which starts from the second column, f.e.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[1,3,5,7],'c':[1,4,7,10],'d':[1,5,9,11]})

def style_diag(data):
    diag_mask = pd.DataFrame("", index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
    min_axis = min(diag_mask.shape)
    diag_mask.iloc[range(min_axis), range(min_axis)] = 'background-color: yellow'
    return diag_mask

df.style.apply(style_diag, axis=None)
```

This gives following output:

[image: table with highlighting along the main diagonal]

*(but actually I don't really get the magic in this function)*

**And I'd like to have a yellow highlight across the diagonal elements 1, 4, 9.**

How can I do that?

Comment: Beside the point, but the function never uses the `data` param and accesses `df` from the global scope, so it looks like one of those should be changed.

Comment: Also beside the point, but you don't need to repeat `range` when you could do something like `r_min_axis = range(min(diag_mask.shape)); diag_mask.iloc[r_min_axis, r_min_axis]`

Comment: Another thing: I found a more elegant way to fill `diag_mask`'s diagonal: `np.fill_diagonal(diag_mask.values, 'background-color: yellow')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly more than a few options here depending on the exact needs. One approach would be to create a mask of the same shape as your DataFrame with the diagonals at the desired offset filled with `True`s to conditionally apply styles.

#### The approach and usage

```python
def style_diag(df_: pd.DataFrame, offset: int = 0) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Create empty styles DataFrame
    style_df = pd.DataFrame('', index=df_.index, columns=df_.columns)

    # Create a 2D False mask
    mask = np.zeros(df_.shape, dtype=bool)

    # Find diagonal indices at an offset and replace values with True
    rows, cols = np.indices(mask.shape)
    mask[np.diag(rows, k=offset), np.diag(cols, k=offset)] = True

    # Set diagonal styles using mask
    style_df[mask] = 'background-color:yellow'
    return style_df
```

This can be used like:

```python
df.style.apply(style_diag, offset=1, axis=None)
```

Which produces the following results:

[image: Styled DataFrame with offset 1 diagonal highlighted yellow]

Similarly this can be used without an offset to produce the original output:

```python
df.style.apply(style_diag, axis=None)
```

[image: Styled DataFrame with main diagonal highlighted yellow]

Or even with negative offsets:

```python
df.style.apply(style_diag, offset=-2, axis=None)
```

[image: Styled DataFrame with offset -2 diagonal highlighted yellow]

### How it works

We start with an empty False mask of the same shape as our DataFrame:

```python
mask = np.zeros(df_.shape, dtype=bool)

# array([[False, False, False, False],
#        [False, False, False, False],
#        [False, False, False, False],
#        [False, False, False, False]])
```

From here we need to find the diagonal indices in order to replace the values on the diagonal with `True`. There is a function [np.diag_indices_from](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag_indices_from.html), however, unfortunately this does not directly support offset diagonals.

Let's instead grab the indices for this mask using [np.indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html)

```python
rows, cols = np.indices(mask.shape)

# rows
# array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [2, 2, 2, 2],
#        [3, 3, 3, 3]])
# cols
# array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

We can now use the [np.diag](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html) function on both `rows` and `cols` which does natively support offsets (`k`). (For this example, `offset` is 1)

```python
np.diag(rows, k=offset)
# array([0, 1, 2])

np.diag(cols, k=offset)
# array([1, 2, 3])
```

We can use the results from diag as indexers to update our mask

```python
mask[np.diag(rows, k=offset), np.diag(cols, k=offset)] = True

# array([[False,  True, False, False],
#        [False, False,  True, False],
#        [False, False, False,  True],
#        [False, False, False, False]])
```

Now we have a well formatted mask that can be used easily apply style strings.

```python
style_df[mask] = 'background-color:yellow'

#   a                        b                        c                        d
# 0    background-color:yellow                                                  
# 1                             background-color:yellow                         
# 2                                                      background-color:yellow
# 3
```

---

#### Complete working example with imports and version numbers used

```python
import numpy as np  # v1.26.2
import pandas as pd  # v2.1.4

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'b': [1, 3, 5, 7],
    'c': [1, 4, 7, 10],
    'd': [1, 5, 9, 11]
})


def style_diag(df_: pd.DataFrame, offset: int = 0) -> pd.DataFrame:
    style_df = pd.DataFrame('', index=df_.index, columns=df_.columns)
    mask = np.zeros(df_.shape, dtype=bool)
    rows, cols = np.indices(mask.shape)
    mask[np.diag(rows, k=offset), np.diag(cols, k=offset)] = True
    style_df[mask] = 'background-color:yellow'
    return style_df


df.style.apply(style_diag, offset=1, axis=None)
```

[image: Styled DataFrame with offset 1 diagonal highlighted yellow]

Answer (score 1):

You could use math to calculate the indexes to highlight, but I think it's easier to just [`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

```
df.style.apply(lambda d: style_diag(d).shift(axis=1), axis=None)
```

[image: table with highlighting along the diagonal starting from the second column]

Comment: thank you for all the hints "Beside the point" above! .apply(lambda d: style_diag(d).shift(axis=1), axis=None) looks easy, but gives an error " float' object has no attribute 'rstrip' "

Comment: @Yulia I have no idea why you're getting that error and the dataframe in the question doesn't do that. The problem might be in some other part of your code.